# Preventing etag from being searched in a list search

Tags: sharepoint-online, list, search, modern-experience, sharepoint-search

A SharePoint list structure:

| Title |
| --- |
| AAA |
| BBB |

Title is searchable, queryable, retrievable (default configuration in search schema).

In the *Search this list* box, I type AA* and then *enter*

| Results |
| --- |
| AAA |
| BBB |

So I launched this request to look at all the data of the BBB item to investigate why it is included in a AA* search results:
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/sites/mydomain.sharepoint.com:/sites/sitename:/lists/listname/items/itemid?expand=fields

To find that there is an odata.etag field that starts with AA.
There is also an eTag field with the same value.

To be sure, I've typed etags (beginning of etag with a trailing star, or complete etags) and the search found the item. Based on its etag.

There is a sharepoint crawled property named Etag, mapped to nothing by default.
I've mapped it to a new managed property with searchable, queryable, retrievable unchecked. After re-indexing the list, nothing changed. Etag still has an impact on results.

So my first question is:
How to prevent etag from being searched when I search my list?

The same question but asked another way: how to search only on the Title column and not having anything else being searched for the string typed in the *search this list* box?

What are the crawled properties that should be mapped and turned not searchable through managed properties? Or is there another way to achieve this?

At the very least, which crawled property represents this list item etag?